# Id in sub-document serializing as _id in Mongo C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a class that looks like this:

```
   public class SyncData<T>
   {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
        public ObjectId MongoId { get; set; }

        [BsonIgnore]
        public string Id => MongoId.ToString();

        public T Data { get; set; }

        //etc.

   }
```

Sometimes the Data object has a Id field that C# is automatically serializing to _id when it saves it to Mongo.

How can I get it to stop serializing the Id to _id without having access to whatever type is being stored in the generic T Data property.

Comment: Do you know anything about those types, like e.g. in which namespace they are or something that would help grouping them together in a sort of blacklist fashion?

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow know the types upfront:

Given a type

```
public class SomeTypeWithAnIdProperty
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
```

you would do this at the start of your application:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<SomeTypeWithAnIdProperty>(cm => cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.Id));
```

If you don't know the types but you know something about them, e.g. 
 - they all implement a certain interface or
 - they all sit in a certain namespace or
 - you can white-list all other types
then you could do something like this (again, at the start of your application):

```
var conventionPack = new ConventionPack { new IgnoreIdFieldConvention() };
ConventionRegistry.Register("Do not deserialize _id field", conventionPack, t => t.Namespace == "Some.Name.Space"); // via namespace
ConventionRegistry.Register("Do not deserialize _id field", conventionPack, t => t != typeof(SyncData<>)); // white-list approach
ConventionRegistry.Register("Do not deserialize _id field", conventionPack, t => typeof(IDisposable).IsAssignableFrom(t)); // via an interface

public class IgnoreIdFieldConvention : ConventionBase
{
    public void Apply(BsonMemberMap memberMap)
    {
        memberMap.ClassMap.UnmapProperty("Id");
    }
}
```

Comment: We do not know the types.  We provide this as a nuget package.  The nuget package works great except that it serializes Id as _id in sub documents. I will give the whitelist option a shot:

ConventionRegistry.Register("Do not deserialize _id field", conventionPack, t => t != typeof(SyncData<>)); // white-list approach